# Is there a way for Snow Leopard to remember previously unidentified USB keyboards?

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard, usb

I have an arbitrary Dell USB keyboard that I use with my MBP running Snow Leopard.  Everytime I plug the keyboard in, or reboot my computer, Keyboard Setup Assistant pops up saying the keyboard needs to be identified before it can be used.  Once I follow its instructions, I can proceed to use this keyboard.

Is there some way my computer can automatically identify this keyboard in the future so I don't have to run Keyboard Setup Assistant?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem with my keyboard. I did some Googling and learned that in order for my Mac to "remember" my keyboard the file /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist needed to be changed. The problem was that I couldn't change that file because I was logged in as a non-administrator user. The solution was to login with the administrator account, connect and configure the keyboard, logout and never have that problem again. :-)